# Verification of proof: $f(x) = e^x$ is continuous at $a = 2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

$$|e^x-e^2|<\epsilon$$

So if $x<2$ then $2-x<\delta $

Calculations:
$$e^2-e^x<\epsilon$$
$$-e^x<\epsilon -e^2 $$
$$e^x>e^2-\epsilon$$
$$x>\ln(e^2-\epsilon)$$
$$-x<-\ln(e^2-\epsilon)$$
$$2-x<2-\ln(e^2-\epsilon)$$

Then we get:
$$2-x<2-\ln(e²-\epsilon) = \delta_1 $$

And then for $x>2$:

$x-2<\delta$

$$e^x-e^2<\epsilon $$
Calculations:
$$e^x<\epsilon+e^2 $$
$$x<\ln(\epsilon+e^2)$$
$$x-2<\ln(\epsilon+e^2)-2$$

Then we get:
$$x-2<\ln(\epsilon+e^2)-2=\delta_2$$

So that means $\delta=\min{(\delta_1,\delta_2)}$

Comment: Considering that you're looking for solution verification, I would suggest that you detail the *by some calculation* which are too fuzzy.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I will edit

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I have a question, why don't we choose $\delta = 1$ as one of the possible results. In other solutions there is always $\delta = 1$

Comment: How is $e^x$ defined for you?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What do you mean by how it is defined?

Comment: @BiliDebili Inverse function of logarithm or $\sum x^n /n!$ for example. Your proof is for sure depending on that knowledge!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net As far as I know, the exponental function is inverse of the natural logarithm if that is what you mean. We just recently took that sumation notation but I haven't looked into it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, your proof is working. There is however some important pitfalls:

1. You write a succession of inequalities without stating if those are equivalent. This is however critical if you want to go reverse, i.e. if $\vert x-2 \vert < \delta$ then $\vert e^x - e^2 \vert < \epsilon$ which is what is at the end required.
2. You can't take the logarithm of negative numbers. This is the case for example when $\epsilon > e^2$. You have to deal with those cases.

As you know the Mean value theorem, a prove can be:

It exists $c \in (x, 2)$ such that:

$$\vert e^x - e^2\vert = e^c \vert x - 2 \vert \le e^3 \vert x - 2 \vert$$ providing that $\vert x - 2 \vert \lt 1$. And also

$$\vert e^x - e^2\vert = e^c \vert x - 2 \vert \le e^3 \vert x - 2 \vert \le \epsilon$$ if $\vert x - 2 \vert \lt \delta$ for $\delta \lt \min(\epsilon / e^3, 1)$.

Comment: I am a first year undergraduate. Well I just know how the graph of $e^x$ looks like and derivatives and so on...

How is it defined otherwise?

Comment: So you know that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$? Do you also know the Mean value theorem?

Comment: Yes I do know the mean value theorem. @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: The thing is that we first took continuous functions and then the mean value theorem, when we took a look at derivatives

Comment: @BiliDebili I added a proof based on MVT.

Comment: I understand what you meant to ask me before. We defined the continuous function, so that a limit exists for every point, with the limit definition without the mean value. It is very good to also see this kind of solution!

Comment: Knowing that this proof in mostly interesting to get a required bound of $\vert x-2 \vert$. Because if you look at the background MVT uses differentiability... which implies continuity!

Answer (score 1):

$e^x$ is a monotonic function. So if we solve

$$e^{2\pm\delta}=e^2\pm\epsilon,$$ (assuming $e^2>\epsilon$) the smallest solution in $\delta$ will indeed do.

Hence,

$$\delta\le\min(\ln(e^2-\epsilon),\ln(e^2+\epsilon)).$$

---

Anyway, these bounds look complicated as they involve logarithms. We can simplify using the inequality $\dfrac{x-1}x<\ln x<x-1$:

$$\ln(e^2+\epsilon)=2+\ln(1+\frac\epsilon{e^2})>2+\frac\epsilon{e^2+\epsilon}.$$
$$\ln(e^2-\epsilon)=2+\ln(1-\frac\epsilon{e^2})<2-\frac\epsilon{e^2}.$$

Finally, a suitable elementary bound is

$$\delta\le\min(\frac\epsilon{e^2+\epsilon},\frac\epsilon{e^2})=\frac\epsilon{e^2+\epsilon}.$$

Below, the exact bounds in black & green, and approximate, tighter bounds in khaki & yellowish.

[image]

Comment: What program do you use for graphing ?

Comment: @BiliDebili: Microsoft Mathematics.

Comment: What is more correct, to use the expression in a neighbourhood with a $\delta \leq \min (....,....)$ or that we use two exact numbers : $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. Are both correct or is one superior to the other?

Comment: @BiliDebili: you must prove that for any $\epsilon$ there is a suitable $\delta$. The proof can be constructive or not.

Comment: What does a constructive proof mean ?